# ScrollView in Framelayout in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want a Vertical ScrollView on a FrameLayout in which some textviews are present which goes away from screen boundary. But When we want to scroll, Scroll View doesn't work. I don't know How it will be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bar_bg">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/back_btn"
            android:id="@+id/btn_ShowOrderDetail_Back" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"></Button>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/tv_ShowOrderDetail_Header" android:text="Submitted Order"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/logout_icon"
            android:id="@+id/btn_ShowOrderDetail_Logout" android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"></Button>
    </FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView_ShowMyOrderDetail"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|bottom"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dip">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_IBX" android:text="IBX"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="IBX" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="40dip"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ParsedIBX"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Cage"
            android:text="Cage"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
            android:text="Cage" android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ParsedCage"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/divider_280"
            android:id="@+id/img_SubmittedOrder_divider" android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/divider_280"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:id="@+id/img_SubmittedOrder_divider2"
            android:layout_marginTop="235dip"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_SiteVisitors"
            android:text="Site Visitors"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Number1" android:text="(1"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dip" android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Visitor1" android:text="Visitor1"
            android:visibility="invisible"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dip" android:layout_marginTop="150dip"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Visitor2" android:text="Visitor2"
            android:visibility="invisible"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dip" android:layout_marginTop="210dip"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Visitor5" android:text="Visitor5"
            android:visibility="invisible"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dip" android:layout_marginTop="190dip"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Visitor4" android:text="Visitor4"
            android:visibility="invisible"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="15dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dip" android:layout_marginTop="170dip"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Visitor3" android:text="Visitor3"
            android:visibility="invisible"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Number2"
            android:text="(2"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Number3"
            android:text="(3"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Number4"
            android:text="(4"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_Number5"
            android:text="(5"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_StartDate"
            android:text="Start Date"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="260dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_EndDate"
            android:text="End Date"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="240dip"
            android:text="Start Date" android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ParsedStartDate"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="260dip"
            android:text="End Date" android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ParsedEndDate"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="280dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_DeliverPackages"
            android:text="Deliver Packages to Cage/Suit:"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="280dip"
            android:layout_gravity="left|right" android:layout_marginLeft="240dip"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ParsedDeliverPackages"
            android:text="Selected"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_AdditionalInfo"
            android:text="Additional Information"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:layout_gravity="left|right"
            android:layout_marginTop="320dip" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ParsedAdditionalInfo"
            android:text="Error additional Info"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/divider_280"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:id="@+id/img_SubmittedOrder_divider3"
            android:layout_marginTop="340dip"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="345dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_CustomerInternalRef"
            android:text="Customer Internal Reference"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="375dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_GeneralInfo"
            android:text="General Information"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="405dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ContactInfo"
            android:text="Contact Details"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="435dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ContactInfoName"
            android:text="Name:"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="435dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ContactInfoParsedName"
            android:text="Name"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="465dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ContactInfoEmail"
            android:text="Email:"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="465dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ContactInfoParsedEmail"
            android:text="Email"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="495dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ContactInfoContactPhone"
            android:text="Contact Phone:"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dip" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="495dip" android:id="@+id/tv_SubmittedOrder_ContactInfoParsedContactPhone"
            android:text="Contact Phone"></TextView>
    </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame Layout is generally used to hold one child at a time.
See this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Try to use Table Layout Instead.

Answer (score 1):

Frame Layout doesn't allow you to use Scrollview Over it. Best Way if you use relative or Table Layout in your Code.

Answer (score -2):

To get FrameLayout inside ScrollView, do this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutHeader1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1440dp"
             >
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this question is ScrollView inside FrameLayout not Frame Layout inside ScrollView